# Designing barrier to stop only non-hooved animals

Tags: fauna, engineering, architecture, animal-locomotion

We have [barriers that stop hooved animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_grid) by taking advantage their hooves fitting into slats between metal bars/rods, meaning they refuse to pass the barricade because it limits their mobility. However, let's say I want to restrict the movement of everything *but* hooved animals, because the hooved animals are livestock and rest are dangerous wildlife.

How could I design an obstacle which could do this? Good responses will restrict the movement of all legged, non-[ungulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungulate) land animals and be as mechanically simple, low-tech, low-maintenance, and mass-producible as possible.

Comment: Do "shepherd with an old rifle" or "dogs" count as barriers?

Comment: Neither dogs nor a shepherd with an old rifle do much when *Smilodon populator* comes knocking, and dogs are non-selective, they'll chase away anything. Good ideas, though.

Comment: Shepherd with grandpa's old RPG-7 it is.

Comment: @gs automate the shepherd and use a 20 mil :P

Comment: Why do you want to let your livestock pass whenever they please? If they go out into the part of the world with dangerous wildlife without supervision, they'll become lunch.

Comment: Any hooved animals, or are you working with a specific livestock?  Not all hooves are the same.

Comment: Specifically, tailless antilocaprids (two toes per limb) with great jumping ability (2+ meters vertical).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Electric step plates**

Hooves are made of the same material as your nails and hair (keratin), they are not as conductive as skin on paws. A paw placed on these would cause a minor shock to the owner and would cause them to retreat. A hoof stepping on these would not cause enough current to bother the animal.

Answer (score 6):

Tallish cones, not too sharp but still painful to step on with soft paws, deployed densely enough so that hooves do not go between them + shorter, sharp spikes between the cones. These positioned in a corridor over sufficiently long distance so that they cannot be jumped over.

Most other animals have more or less softer paw pads, so they cannot easily step on the cones because they hurt them, and the spikes will hurt them even more. Hooves, on the other hand, manage the cones easily, and they don't reach the spikes at all.

Comment: A cow is a decently heavy animal with somewhat small hooves, also IIRC their hooves are not exactly flat, such ground texture could cause damage to hooves due to greatly increased local pressure due to animal's own weight. Then we have horses that too would use that road, especially if mounted. Dangerous if you ask me.

Comment: @Vesper I am aware of that, I have lived on a farm. If the cones are spaced densely enough, and they are dull enough, situation does not differ from walking on sharp gravel. Soft-pawed animals want to avoid it, but cows and horses do not care. Add spikes to the mix, and soft-pawed animals dread it.

Comment: If they are dense enough not to damage cow hooves then they must be very dense, stacked nails dense. which means lighter pawed animals will be able to walkover them just fine. they will also get clogged with mud and dirt very quickly, letting everything over them.

Comment: @John You missed another factor: they also need to be **dull** enough. Lego brick dull is enough to deter soft-pawed animals (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4dSaxRW5JU) while it does almost nothing to hooves.

Comment: enough to deter well fed domesticated pets, its not going to do anything to an alligator or anything once its clogged.

Comment: @John That is true, and potentially a shortcoming in this method, depending on the fauna, of course. If there are alligators and such, something additional to deal with them should be added.

Comment: I would imagine that like a cow grid, hoofed animals would also be reluctant to step on this, given that it would tend to trap their hooves between the tall cones.

Comment: @MontyWild "deployed densely enough so that hooves do not go between them"

Comment: Cones that a hoof can't go between would tend to trap the hooves as if they had stepped in a 'V' shape, which would be functionally similar to a cattle grid.  If the hooves won't go between the points, what's the point of the lower cones, and how do you allow for animals with different sized hooves?

Comment: @MontyWild What is your reasoning for this "[cones] would tend to trap the hooves as if they had stepped in a 'V' shape"? I just cannot imagine how that would happen.

Comment: @MontyWild ""what's the point of the lower cones" The hooves are hardish and they stay flat, so they on top of the cones. Soft paws however give in, and the part that is between the cones reaches the sharper _spikes_ that puncture holes in the paw pads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen those hand mold impression toys? All those little metal pins sticking up until you press something into them, which you can then see from the other side. Basically, you have a slightly higher tech version of those placed on the ground. They have a basic computer with pattern recognition. The pins stay extended in the air until something steps on them. The computer determines if the pattern matches that of whatever animals are allowed to pass. If something not allowed tries to pass, the pins it is touching are electrified. The animal retreats, and the pins reset themselves. They could even be solar powered or linked to share electricity.  Roll them out almost like a red carpet and you have a strip of land blocked off.

Another nice thing about this idea is that the computer could track what animals attempted to cross at what location/time. They could also be configured with either whitelists or blacklists. Maybe even send an automatic text if an unauthorized animal manages to cross the barrier. Depending on how low tech you want to stay you can pick and choose your added functions.

Answer (score -2):

### [CIWS system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanx_CIWS)

A concrete slab, an elevated white lacquered steel dome, and an automatic macine cannon, all linked with cameras and infrared sensors, detectors, and a powerful computer. The moment a signature set up to be a target comes into sight, the CIWS starts to track, and if the perimeter line is breached, the gun roars to life to turn the intruder into perforated chunks of matter.

The "barrier" is a line on a map. It can't be seen by the target, but the hum of the CIWS spinning up will soon teach survival of the fittest - where fittest is the one that does not enter that field.

Comment: This certainly does not satisfy the "be as mechanically simple, low-tech, low-maintenance, and mass-producible as possible" requirement. At least you have to resupply ammo to this stuff.